# packaging external jars into a jar from command line

Tags: java

I want to package my external jars (that are in lib/) and the jar that I am building of the class files all into one jar. Ive tried to do it as:

```
jar cvf proj.jar -C classes/ . lib/
```

The jar gets built up but when I use this jar in the program, the external jars supposed to be included as lib/ end up missing. So I think this is perhaps not the right way to do this.

I have tried exporting a jar through eclipse too (though I would like to fix the command line stuff) by giving it the location of external jars and I still had the problem of the program unable to locate the external jars.

Comment: "Does not seem to be working" is not a sufficient nor acceptable description of the problem.  Please elaborate on what you mean by "not working".  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Not enough information to go on. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot (by default) nest jars in this fashion.

You *may*, however, use something like [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) to do this, or something like [onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) (or jarjar, or fatjar, etc.) that repackages jar contents into a single, un-nested jar.